# How to represent array in ruby-rails view template?

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am rendering a variable in `rails view`.

```
<%= @data.matrix %>
```

which prints multidimensional array in template like this:

```
[[":23", ":12"],[ ":56", ":12"],[":21", ":23"]]
```

How can I represent the above data in table format that it will actually look like a matrix in `view.html` page for better reading the values row and colum. We also have the information of `@data.row` and `@data.col` in view template.

This is more `HTML` question but is there any way to do it with `rails view` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<table>
  <% JSON.parse(@data.matrix).each do |tuple| %>
    <tr>
      <% tupel.each do |value| %>
        <td><%= value %></td>
      <% end %>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's throwing an error `undefined method `each' for #<String:0x007fef3fb40998>`

That means string is not null

Comment: So `@data.matrix` returns a string and not an array. Looks like JSON, therefore let's parse it as JSON first. Please see my updated answer.

Comment: I tried but it's only printing the `arr[i][0] ..arr[i][col]` value. Please have a look at the screenshot.http://i.imgur.com/pSFWuI0.png

JSON representation of printing matrix section

Comment: You did not tell in your question that each sub-array has more that two values... Updated my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like for multiple array,

```
<table>
  <% @data.matrix.flatten.each do |value| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= value %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```